# Relocate Qt5 installation on Linux

Tags: qt5

Does anyone know, how to relocate the QT5 installation on Linux? Especially, all the set paths of the files in the mkspecs directory?
Any tool or script letting Qt5 create these files again is o.k.

I'd like to deploy the files of QT5's "lib/bin/mkspecs..." via a central repository on other computers to be able to seemingless do the compilation.

And no, I really don't want to use the systems QT5 by some package manager.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted this a few times. It gets really hairy really fast, and my only recommendation is that you re-install to the new location.

The reason is that the path of the installation is hard-coded into so many files in so many locations that even search-replacing them all is really error prone.

Answer (score 0):

1) Download source and make your custom Qt build - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html

2) Make own package\installer of your builded Qt libraries.

If you want own Qt build for run particular application. Then make right installer for that application include all necessary files.